# RequestMapping DisplatcherServlet no mapping found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, controller

My DispatcherServlet is not working correctly.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>userService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/servlet/userService-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>userService</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value ="/user")
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody List<User> getUsers() {
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable int id) throws NotFoundException {
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void delete(@PathVariable int id) throws NotFoundException {
    }
}
```

the servlet:

When I try ´/user´ to get all users it workings fine but when i try to get certain user for example ´user/75´. 75 representing the {id} I'm getting:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/user/75] in DispatcherServlet with name 'userService'
```

not sure why. is my url-pattern wrong? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line `<url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>` of your web.xml to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

This change makes the Dispatcher Servlet catch all requests under '/' whereas in your previous configuration it was catching everying under /user (meaning that your controller's find method would be mapped at `/user/user/{id}`)

Answer (score 2):

With your current confifuration in `web.xml` and your `controller` what you actually have is this:

If you have deployed your webapplication in root dir (ie your webapp is in '/' directory of your tomcat)then to get to all users you go to

```
http://localhost:8080/user/user
```

and to find your specific user you would have to go to

```
http://localhost:8080/user/user/{id}
http://localhost:8080/user/user/75 //in your example
```

If you wanted to use the following format for your REST services

```
http://localhost:8080/user/
http://localhost:8080/user/{id}
```

Then you have to change your servlet mapping to the following:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>userService</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```